# Included all thresholds, code still not generating output

Tags: python, python-3.9

I wanted to create an app that sends a notification depending on what the air quality is around you. I went to IQAir to get the API. With the help of ChatGPT, I created the lines of codes. It shows messages depending on whether the air quality is equal to or below 50, 100, 150, 200, and 300.

This is my first ever Python project, so I learned a lot of the basics like what tools I needed (Python 3.9 to go along with ChatGPT's most updated knowledge, Command on Windows, Notebook++), How to open and save files, etc.

I'm running into an issue where I'm not getting any output from this code. I was wondering if anybody can help?

Thanks in advance!

I created the code so it includes all the possible thresholds from 0-300. However, when I run the file, I am not getting an output. I included 4 different possible messages, and am expecting one of these messages to show up when I run the file, however, I am not getting any out.

```
import requests
from plyer import notification
def get_air_quality_data():
    api_key = 'ac21e268-1ad1-4626-a8bf-244a3200d794'
    url = f'https://api.airvisual.com/v2/nearest_city?key={api_key}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    air_quality = data['data']['current']['pollution']['aqius']
    return air_quality

def show_notification(air_quality):
    thresholds = [50, 100, 150, 200, 300]
    messages = [
        "Air quality is excellent. Enjoy outdoor activities!",
                "Air quality is above 100. Consider outdoor activities.",
        "Air quality is above 150. Limit outdoor activities.",
        "Air quality is above 200. Avoid outdoor activities.",
        "Air quality is above 300. Stay indoors and keep safe."
    ]
    for threshold, message in zip(thresholds, messages):
        if air_quality <= threshold:
            notification.notify(
                title=f"Air Quality Alert ({air_quality})",
                message=message,
                app_icon=None,
            )
            break

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    air_quality = get_air_quality_data()
    show_notification(air_quality)
```

Comment: This works on my machine, replacing the `notification` part with a `print` call to test it's actually hitting that. Maybe `notification` is the issue, I'm not familiar with that module.

Comment: What is the actual air quality value you are receiving?  A value of 301 or greater should not produce any output.  (Note that your descriptions don't match the values - for example, the "above 100" message applies for values 51..100.)

Comment: @Mous thank you so much for the suggestion! I played around with the print call to test and it successfully works. hooray!